# CHM files; is there a standard replacement for this format

Tags: javascript, pdf, cross-platform, chm

Currently I am working in a tool that generates html reports.

The problem with the generated html report is;

- The report used to have too many files (each file has a table consists of 100 to 400 row).
- Number of files may reach to 500K or even more.
- The problem is; When having too many small files, their disk space size used to be huge.

  For example;
  I has a report with 1.3 G files. Its disk space size is 7.9 G bytes.

  One day I tried to compress these 1.3 G files in a single zip file. The resulted file was
  only 110 M bytes !!!!!!!.
- Now I am thinking to put all the report in a single file.
- I am currently thinking about PDF and CHM.
- I don't prefer PDF as the report is already html and has some Javascript codes.
- According to my information; PDF has some limits on Javascript code especially
  when this Javascript changes the appearance of the page (e.g. show/hide table rows).

  This means; CHM is appealing to me. BUT, it doesn't work on linux. I can't generate
  CHM files on linux. In addition, Microsoft's tool that generates the CHM file (hhc.exe)
  failed to handle huge file numbers. It used to display an error message "No enough memory".

So, my question is;

- Is there any other file format that is similar to CHM but is a standard one with an
  available specification?
- In other words, i need some thing that is;

  - Displayed similar to CHM file
  - Has a known specification similar to PDF

If there is not, then why no body think about something like this?!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [John Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Comment: have you considered [MS HTML Help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms670169(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @Philip: HTML Help = .CHM files

Comment: htmlhelp1 to be exact. -2 and -3 are something different.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik there is nothing to replace it with, and specially not multiplatform.

CHM on Windows also doesn't support everything the installed IE does. It runs IE in a special mode.

For Linux support, use the [chmcmd](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/htmlhelp_compiler) compiler from Free Pascal. It's fairly complete, only merged CHM support is not 100%. I get some reports that people with large CHMs also use it on Windows because it is faster and more reliable.

Some Linux distribution might have a standalone installer package for it, otherwise install the Free Pascal package distribution that contains the chmcmd binary (you only need that file for your arch).

The state of viewers outside windows is not great though, many didn't open even my 11MB file.

Though for your cases you probably want to build trunk (that has multicore compression support), CHM doesn't really compress quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best solution I found to this problem.

- Since the report is almost table with information. Then, place all needed info (only info) in json files (or you can say, java script files).
- Since the json file will contain only info, then, you will be able to store a huge amount of info in a single file and the file will not consume except 2 or 3 mega bytes. because it doesn't have any html presentation info.
- Then, have a single HTML file that has the presentation.
- Then, when you want to open a certain HTML table, just open this HTML file. This HTML file will contain javascript code that will do the following:
  1- Load the needed piece of info from the json file
  2- render this json info inside a HTML table.

I hope this answer is helpful